# Create a json object from Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Ruby on Rails form that takes the input and saves it as model attributes. One of the attributes, though, holds json data. I would like to be able to take the data entered into multiple fields and save it as a single JSON object in my models attribute. Is there a way I could do this?

If it helps, I could also make a Hash and convert it to json. Basically I just want to combine multiple input fields into one, then hand it off from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are multiple things to consider here.

The first problem is to get your data out of the HTML form. If you use the standard Rails way of naming your form inputs, it's quite simple.

```
<input name="my_fields[value1]">
<input name="my_fields[value2]">
<input name="my_fields[sub1][value1]">
<input name="my_fields[sub1][value2]">
```

If you name them like that they can be accessed "en bloc" using the `params` hash via `params[:my_fields]`, which gives you another hash containing your data.

Then you have to choose which way to save this data in your model. There are several options:

1. **Use a string attribute**

Just use a `string` or `text` column and assign a JSON string:

```
@my_model.my_data = params[:my_fields].to_json
```

- Pro: A very simple solution.
- Contra: SQL queries virtually impossible. Processing with Rails requires manually parsing of the data string.

2. **Use a serialized hash**

Use a `string` or `text` column and declare it as serializable on your model

```
serialize :my_data, Hash
```

Then you can use this column as it was a simple hash and Rails will perform the reading and writing operations.

```
@my_model.my_data = params[:my_fields]
```

- Pro: Still a simple solution. No messing with JSON strings. Processing with Rails much easier.
- Contra: SQL queries virtually impossible. A call to `to_json` is necessary if you need a real JSON string.

3. **Use specialized JSON database types**

In case you need to be able to query the database using SQL the solutions above won't work. You have to use specialized types for that.

Many DBMS provide structured datatypes in form of XML or even JSON types. (PostgreSQL for example)

- Pro: Database queries are possible.
- Contra: Custom parsing and serialization necessary, migrations ditto. This solution might be over-engineered.

**Update:** Since Rails 5 JSON column types are supported. If you are using PostgreSQL or MySQL just use `t.json` (or `t.jsonb`) in your migration and use that attribute like a regular hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can save all multiple files as text in JSON format and when you need parse the field.

Ex:

```
a = JSON.parse('{"k1":"val1"}')
a['k1'] => "val1"
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't help with grabbing the data from the form and combining it all together, which is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably looking for an `before_save` that takes all your model attributes and create a JSON format using `.to_json` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into the new JSONB format of Postgres.  I think this gets you all the PROS, and none of the CONS:

http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/